# Using jest.mock for multiple tests

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to write a unit test for the firebase auth createUserWithEmailAndPassword() function.  I have a helper class that I've written that calls this function and returns a promise.  I'm trying to mock the firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword() function in my test and it works but only for one test case.  I can't figure out how to change the mock for createUserWithEmailAndPassword() for other test cases.  I've used jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce() to reject the promise and return an error code.  What I'd like to do is re-mock with mockRejectdValueOnce() to handle alternate error codes and mockResolveValueOnce() to handle the successful case.  I've tried moving the jest.mock(...) into the test itself but the mock no longer works and it calls the real function instead.  here's the helper class that I'm trying to test.

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

const config = {
  apiKey: "somevalue",
  authDomain: "somevalue",
  databaseURL: "somevalue",
  projectId: "somevalue",
  storageBucket: "somevalue",
  messagingSenderId: "somevalue",
  appId: "somevalue",
  measurementId: "somevalue"
};

class Firebase {

  private auth: app.auth.Auth;

  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = app.auth();
  }

  public async register(email: string, password: string, name: string): Promise<any> {
    return await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

}

export default new Firebase();
```

And here is the test that I've written that works:

```
import { FirebaseAccountManager } from './FirebaseAccountManager';
import IAccount from './IAccount';

jest.mock('firebase/app', () => (
  {
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    initializeApp: jest.fn(),
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce({
      code: 'auth/invalid-email'
    }),
  }
));

describe('test', () => {

  test('aTest', async () => {
    const newAccount: IAccount = { firstName: 'asdf', lastName: 'asdf', email: 'asdf.adf.com', password: 'qwer', phoneNumber: '', workStatus: '', city: '', postalCode: '', country: '' }

    const fam = new FirebaseAccountManager();
    await expect(fam.register(newAccount)).rejects.toEqual({
      code: 'auth/invalid-email'
    });

  });
});
```

if I move the mock into the test itself it stops working.  i'd like to write more tests using the mock but am not sure how to do this.  Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but one way to do it would be to chain multiple `mockResolvedValueOnce` and `mockRejectedValueOnce` calls instead of having a single one, in whatever order you expect to use them in your test.

From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvalueoncevalue):

```
test('async test', async () => {
  const asyncMock = jest
    .fn()
    .mockResolvedValue('default')
    .mockResolvedValueOnce('first call')
    .mockResolvedValueOnce('second call');

  await asyncMock(); // first call
  await asyncMock(); // second call
  await asyncMock(); // default
  await asyncMock(); // default
});
```

Comment: This works but is there not a way to specify the mock in the test?